# Tag Mismatch error | An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest): Tag mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, tags, failed-installation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj6Ny.png)

**Tag Mismatch error | An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest): Tag mismatch!**

1--> An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: tag mismatch.
2--> SDK component were not install?Tag Mismatch
3--> While installing Android studio flamingo version unable to downloads SDK?

```
Preparing "Install Sources for Android 33 (revision: 1)".
```

Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-33_r01.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 33: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Sources for Android 33 (revision: 1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-33_r02.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 33: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.2 (revision: 33.0.2)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r33.0.2-windows.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.2: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.2 (revision: 33.0.2)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 34.0.3)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r34.0.3-windows.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform-Tools: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android SDK Platform-Tools (revision: 34.0.3)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 32.1.13)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-10086546.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Android Emulator (revision: 32.1.13)" failed.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 33: Tag mismatch!.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 33: Tag mismatch!.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 33.0.2: Tag mismatch!.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform-Tools: Tag mismatch!.
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Tag mismatch!.

Preparing "Install Sources for Android 33 (revision: 1)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-33_r01.zip
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Tag mismatch!
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 33: Tag mismatch!.
"Install Sources for Android 33 (revision: 1)" failed.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-33_r02.zip

now I tried to update latest version of JDK and off firewall , my internet connection is very good state, and tried with Administrator android studio and I try to fix this bug since last week but it doesn't work.
I tried so many time install/uninstall but failed to download SDK?
i tried most of the internet solution and chat GPT solution but its not resolve?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the IDE log? Secondly, close Android Studio and delete the problematic SDK from here
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Answer (score 1):

I followed all over the internet and tried every solution but still the tag mismatch issue persists. My problem got resolved through the last step.

**Method**-->1 The solution for this is:
Run Android Studio as Administrator.
Re run the update.
It will work.

**Method**-->2 And I notice some setting about Force https//... to be fetched using http://...
After using it, my download run normally:

**Method**-->3 Download zip file from this location
Extract it and move the emulator folder image for emulator folder into the SDK folder image for SDK folder
I hope it works for you as well, I was using Windows 10 Pro 64bit.

**Method**-->4 I experienced the same issue as i tried to install Android API 27. Each time i use the SDK manager it downloads but fails to install. Here is how i fixed it
Run Android Studio as administrator
Open SDK Manager
Click on "edit" found close to "Android SDK location"
It opens a window that show a list of "Android SDK Platform" you have downloaded but not installed.
it shows API 27- 62MB. I clicked on this to install. After it successfully install my app works fine.I hope this fix works for you

**Method**-->5 in my case,I checked windows update where some drivers were pending and some were incomplete.
Then I restarted by updating windows with proper network then android studio installed properly and SDK works.

Comment: > Download zip file from this location Extract it and move the emulator folder image for emulator folder into the SDK folder image for SDK folder 
-- this solved it, I moved the downloaded `emulator` (eg: `https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-windows_x64-11237101.zip`) to `C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator`